# Unknown file extension ".png" in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, import, png

I have a React project (created with create-react-app).
In my project folder, I have png images. When I try to import them into my .js file like this..

```
import wateringCan from './imgs/wateringCan.png'
import candySeeds from './imgs/candySeeds.png'
import growLight from './imgs/growLight.png'
```

I get the error

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".png"
```

I expect the images to just work.
If it makes any difference, they are tiny (~150byte) black and white pixel images.
But I tried a regular sized image too and get the same error.